# Remove extra commas in TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `TemplateField` which has some concatenated items with commas between. This is to show an address (stored in multiple columns) in a single column. It works, but I would like to remove the extra commas that appear if any fields are blank in the database.

As it's not a string, I am not sure how to do this. Please help!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Address">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
<%# Eval("claddr1") + ", " + Eval("claddr2") + ", " + Eval("claddr3") + ", " + Eval("claddr4") + ", " + Eval("claddr5") + ", " + Eval("claddr6") + ", " + Eval("clcity") + ", " + Eval("clstate") + ", " + Eval("clzip")%>
</asp:Label>                        
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You can use the ternary operator to put logic in there to just show a blank if the eval ends up being a blank string.  It allows you to put c# logic inside those tags.

Comment: you can write logic for assigning label1.txt in C# code don't give as eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out nulls with LINQ and then join the rest together:

```
String.Join(", ",
            new string[]{"claddr1", "claddr2",
                         "claddr3", "claddr4",
                         "claddr5", "claddr6",
                         "clcity", "clstate",
                         "clzip"}
               .Select(x => Eval(x))
               .Where(x => x!= null)
           )
```

I would also suggest to put this into code behind, to keep markup nice and clean:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
<%# GetFormattedAddress() %>

protected string GetFormattedAddress()
{
    return String.Join(", ",
            new string[]{"claddr1", "claddr2",
                         "claddr3", "claddr4",
                         "claddr5", "claddr6",
                         "clcity", "clstate",
                         "clzip"}
               .Select(x => Eval(x))
               .Where(x => x!= null)
           );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it worked except the extra commas remain in the address!

Comment: @JayF1, that's weird. If the field is empty in the DB, does it come out as null, or an empty string?

Comment: The empty ones show as NULL when I query the database

Comment: @JayF1, how do they appear if you debug the C# code? As null as well?

Comment: When trying to view the value in the debug window I'm just getting "The name 'claddr1' does not exist in the current context", etc

Comment: @JayF1, that message would appear if you where looking for a value of variable `claddr1`. What you really should be looking for is `Eval("claddr1")` or Eval("other field name") which is NULL in the db